# How to chain SSL certificates in Perl?

Tags: perl, ssl

Perl newbie here.
I need to chain an intermediate CA x509 certificate to my client certificate.

```
Net::SSLeay::set_cert_and_key($ctx, $crt, $key);
my $bio = Net::SSLeay::BIO_new_file("subca.crt", 'r');
my $x509 = Net::SSLeay::PEM_read_bio_X509($bio);
Net::SSLeay::CTX_add_extra_chain_cert($ctx, $x509)
    and die_if_ssl_error("CTX_add_extra_chain_cert"); # It dies here.
```

The certificate is in pem format. Can anyone help?

Edit: I have found that the call to "Net::SSLeay::PEM_read_bio_X509()" returns 0, which is an error condition.

Comment: What's the error that it dies with? I think that PEM_read_bio() may return a reference to an array, and you have to add each certificate in the reference separately. Check out the [IO::Socket::SSL source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.84/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm) for an example.

Comment: I don't know how to get a meaningfull error description. It dies like that: "20397: CTX_add_extra_chain_cert"

Comment: What type of object or reference is `$x509`?

Comment: According to the API doc, it's "value corresponding to openssl's X509 structure". I have solved the problem, without using BIO_* or PEM_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what I was looking for:

```
Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey_file($ctx, $key, &Net::SSLeay::FILETYPE_PEM)
    and die_if_ssl_error("private key");
Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_certificate_chain_file($ctx, $crt)
    and die_if_ssl_error("CTX_use_certificate_chain_file");
```

$crt contains 2 certificates, first the client certificate, followed by the intermediate one.